# how to use knockout observable as json object

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I used an object like this with knockout

```
            var Employee = function () {
                self.Name = ko.observable();
                self.Id = ko.observable();
                self.Manager = ko.observable();
                self.Title = ko.observable();
                self.Salary = ko.observable();
                self.Age = ko.observable();
            };
```

and the viewmodel look like this

```
            var EmployeesViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                var url = "/api/employees";
                var refresh = function() {
                    $.getJSON(url, { }, function(data) { self.Employees(data); });
                };

                // Public data properties
                self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.newEmployee = ko.observable(new Employee());

                // Public operations
                self.addEmployee = function (model, event) {
                    var item = self.newEmployee();
                    alert(model); // always undefined
                    self.Employees.push(item);
                };
                self.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
                    self.Employees.remove(employee);
                    removeEmployee(employee);
                };
                refresh();
            };
            ko.applyBindings(new EmployeesViewModel());
```

in **self.addEmployee** method when I use the **item** I get null value although the item is added to the list and is displayed in the grid.

edit:
the problem in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/magedfarag/b4tsX/

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for the problem in action http://jsfiddle.net/magedfarag/b4tsX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your `Employee` instances incorrectly: `self` is undefined there, you need `this`. Also, `alert(item.Name)` will display a function, as `item.Name` is also an observable (you're unwrapping only the `self.newEmployee` observable, but its properties remain observables).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4tsX/2/).

Comment: Thank you. you saved me. I reviewed the code many time and overlooked this silly mistake.